# Как удалить из списка авторов в android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как удалить лишних авторов  из списка в комите android studio? нашел подобную тему, но она без ответа [тема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623066/android-studio-remove-author-permanently-from-git-commit-dropdown-list#new-answer)